# Middleware 'auth' clarification

Tags: php, laravel-5

Im using Laravel 5.8 and I got the following situation:

I have a simple form with a button which sends a delete request to a route. The form works like this: When the button is pressed, the form's action redirects me to the URL localhost/delete/4 where 4 is the id of the entry in the database, and there the route kicks in and the controller deletes my entry.

However, unauthenticated users do not have access to the form's button, and the route is protected by the middleware 'auth'.
But, if I, as an unauthenticated user, type in the adress bar localhost/delete/4, I get a method unsupported error, which is expected because I send a get request to a delete type route.

But my question is why do I get this error at all? Since the route is protected by the middleware against unauthenticated users, why does the request reach the route since it should be blocked by the middleware?

Below you got the route:

```
Route::delete('/delete/{id}', ['uses' => 'LibraryController@getLibraryDelete', 'middleware' => 'auth']);
```

Oh, as a side note, if a change the route to receive get requests, and try again, the middleware works fine

Comment: The `delete` version of the route, which you have defined, is protected by the middleware. The `get` version, which you don't have defined, can't be protected as it doesn't exist. So you get the `MethodNotSupported` error.

Comment: @TimLewis but then, shouldn't I get a "route doesn't exist" error since the get version doesn't exist and the delete one is protected and the request can't reach it?

Comment: ugh, I'll just  ````$this->middleware('auth')->except();```` in the controller's construct

Comment: Well no, the route does exist, just the method `GET` is not supported... Maybe odd wording, but the it's just the precedence of catches; you'd get a `NotSupported`, then a `404`, then the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

The route is checked first before going to the middleware and controller...
So if the route was not found actually the script doesn't know which middleware or controller to go to...

--

Here is a good use case for example someone want to define the following routes

Route::get('/question/{id}', 'QuestionController@view');

`GET /question/1` is public for all users and returns the question itself (read only)

but

Route::patch('/question/{id}', 'QuestionController@edit')->middleware('auth');

`PATCH /question/1` is only authenticated user can edit question...

So it's acceptable that different methods can have different middlewares or no middlewares for the same route... 
And that some methods are not defined/allowed

--

The method is unsupported because your defined route is for deletes only as in `::delete` method you used

Delete request is either a HTTP POST request with a query called "_method" and value "delete" or in supported browser an HTTP DELETE request

When the user type the url manually in their address bar it's a GET request which can be handled by this route method ::get

Available routing methods from latest documentation: (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)

```
Route::get($uri, $callback);
Route::post($uri, $callback);
Route::put($uri, $callback);
Route::patch($uri, $callback);
Route::delete($uri, $callback);
Route::options($uri, $callback);
```

Plus special route `::any` which accepts any method

In laravel if the user reach a url that is defined but with a Method that's not defined in routes you get this "Method unsupported"

The method unsupported error is irrelevant to auth middleware in this case ... it's just about routing

Comment: @SirNash wow, I surely did not expect this "The route is evaluated first before going to the middleware and controller..."

Comment: I edited my answer with a better use-case when you can define two routes for same url...

Comment: @GrosuCosminIonut You can read more about the lifecycle itself here 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/lifecycle , it's the section "Dispatching Request" 
which says that once services providers are loaded the request is sent to the router which then decides which route->middleware->controller to run.... in case of method not allowed it means it never found the corresponding route...